# Markdown editor with couple specific features

Tags: windows, markdown, editor

I'm looking for a Markdown editor; of course, I've reviewed a lot of them, but could not find a couple features which could boost the productivity of my current tasks:

1. Inserting web links. This is a simple routine task but I need to automate manual steps for a lot of daily copy/paste actions - if I paste the link into the md document then it should retrieve the website title and wrap this into [web site title](link) automatically.
2. The same automated wrapping by md syntax for images on the web, pasted by link.
3. For local images, the ability to drop image into the md document, then auto-wrap by markdown picture syntax and put the images into a (preconfigured) subfolder alongside with the .md document.

It should work on Windows.

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question to include which markdown editors you've looked at and why they didn't meet your needs. Also, include information such as whether you need it to be WYSIWYG, whether it must be a standalone application or can be e.g., a macro package for another program such as Notepad++ or Microsoft Word.

Comment: I think vscode has very good editor for MD files, also Visual Studio has good renderer for MD file

Comment: vscode and vs don't have a described features. but thank you for the idea to add 'WYSIWYG' keyword to my google request and now I found a few candidates. and currently testing Obsidian with plugins